# Is there a Geo type literal? Or only sub-type

Tags: sql, postgresql, gis, postgis

Some databases support literals of the various `GEO` type, for example in Postgres, you can do:

```
SELECT POINT '1,1';
```

And in Postgres it enforces the sub-type at the column level:

```
SELECT POINT '1,1' UNION ALL SELECT LINE '0,0,1,1';
```

> ERROR:  UNION could not convert type line to point

However, some databases allow using various `GEO` types in the same column (such as BigQuery, as one example).

1. Is it possible to use the `GEO`|`GEOMETRY`|`GEOGRAPHY` keyword itself for literal creation, for example something like `SELECT GEO '1,1' FROM tbl` ?
2. Is it possible to have a `GEO` column that supports any sub-type within it?

Comment: You might want to take a look on this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340031/postgis-create-table-with-multiple-geometry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code seems to do the job.
Having said that, the fact that we can do something doesn't necessarily mean we should do it.

A similar [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340031/postgis-create-table-with-multiple-geometry) states:

> "Client applications usually deny the work with a single generic geometry type column as well as multiple geometry columns in one table!"

```
          select 'POINT(1 1)'::geography
union all select 'LINESTRING(0 0,1 1)'::geography
```

| geography |
| --- |
| 0101000020E6100000000000000000F03F000000000000F03F |
| 0102000020E61000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F03F000000000000F03F |

```
          select 'POINT(1 1)'::geometry
union all select 'LINESTRING(0 0,1 1)'::geometry
```

| geometry |
| --- |
| 0101000000000000000000F03F000000000000F03F |
| 01020000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F03F000000000000F03F |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9aa68487facbe4179d73952d20816b93)

Comment: you can directly cast to `::geography`  (or to `::geometry`)

Comment: @david -- cool! this is the answer I was looking for: `select geography(point) as 'POINT(1 1)' union all select geography(linestring) 'LINESTRING(0 0,1 1)'`

Comment: @JGH - Yep, you are right. It didn't work on the original format used by th OP but is does work on the format I posted. Updated answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to David's answer, the thing about Geo type in PostgreSQL, you should distinguish between

- Old (and mostly obsolete) native PostgreSQL types like POINT and LINE in your example. These cannot be mixed, as each one is a separate SQL type.
- Modern types provided by PostGIS extension: GEOMETRY and GEOGRAPHY.

The GEOMETRY and/or GEOGRAPHY types in most databases, including PostGIS types, try to follow OGC and SQL/MM standards and can contain any collection or mix of points/lines/polygons spatial types. Here a single SQL type (e.g. GEOMETRY) may contain arbitrary spatial type(s).

As for literals, the syntax varies. PostgreSQL supports casts using `'POINT(1 1)'::geometry` syntax, but in all databases you can use equivalent functions like `ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)')` (function names vary across DBMS) to build geometry or geography.